# Need to know the steps to access azure key vault in my Java Springboot application

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-sdk-for-java

How can I access Azure key vault in my sprint boot application?
What do I need to implement in my code and what kind of permission needed in my subscription?

Getting error "Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. " while creating service principal.

Answer (score 0):

***Follow the below given steps and code to fetch and use the azure keyvault in spring boot application :***

1. Run below command in the Azure Cloud Shell to get list of subscriptions and
   `az account list`
2. To Set/select the particular Subscription:
   `az account set -s your\_subscription\_id`
3. Create service principal using the below command:
   `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name myapp --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID`

- Go to Active Directory=> select the service principal app which you have created and note below details:

```
Your Client_ID  
Your Client\_Secret\_Value  
Your Tenant_ID
```

4. Access Azure key vault in sprint boot application by following Below Steps:

- Create a Resource Group in Azure Portal
- Create a Key Vault in Azure Portal by selecting your resource group
- Create secret in Azure key vault and store your secret key.
- Select “Access policies” in left pane of key vault.

[image]

- Click on  **Create**  and select the permissions such as “*Get, List, Recover, Set, Delete, Backup, Restore*” in  **secret permissions**.

[image]

- Click “***Next***” and select the service principal app which you have created and click “***Create***”.

[image]

5. Go to your spring boot application=>Under  *resources*  folder=>  *application.properties*  file, paste  your *Client_ID, Client_Secret_Value, Tenant_ID and Key Vault URL* as shown below:

```java
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=<your_Client_ID>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=<your_Client_Secret>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=<KeyVault_URL>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=<your_Tenant_ID>
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

***References:***

Refer to my [github](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Retrive_secretfrom_Azure_keyvault) repo for the code to access and retrieve secret from Azure key vault.

Answer (score 0):

You should first verify if the `az login` command is working for you.
If properly setup, you should see a message as shown below -
[image]

After this step, you have to add the below dependencies in your pom.xml

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/spring-cloud-azure-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please check the compatibility between spring-boot version and the library-version. It worked for `spring-boot version = 3.1.1` for me

After this you can create a `Configuration` class as follows -

```
@Configuration
public class AzureSecretClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecretClient createSecretClient() {
        return new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl("https://sample-key-vault.azure.net/")
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();
    }

}
```

Now in your service class, you can easily inject the configuration and extract values from key-vault. I have shown an example below -

```
    @Autowired
    AzureSecretClientConfiguration secretClientConfiguration;

SecretClient azureSecrets = secretClientConfiguration.createSecretClient();
           try {
                KeyVaultSecret secret = azureSecrets.getSecret("my-sample-key");


            } catch (ClientAuthenticationException e) {
                //Handle Exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```